# show that $f'(c)\geq 0$ and conclude that $f'(c) = 0$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, continuity

(Fermat’s Theorem) Suppose $f$ is diﬀerentiable in some interval $(a,b)$ containing $c$. If $f(c)\geq f(x)$ for every $x$ in $(a,b)$, then $f'(c) = 0$.

Proof: Since $f'(c)$ exists we know that if ($h_n$) from $n=1$ to $\infty$ converges to zero then the sequence $a_n = [f(c+h_n)−f(c)]/h_n$ converges to $f'(c)$. The proof consists of showing that $f'(c) \leq 0$ and that $f'(c) \geq 0$ from which we conclude that $f'(c) = 0$

please help me how can I show that $f'(c) \geq 0$ and conclude that $f'(c) = 0$.

Comment: Your hint is that $f(c+h_n) \leq f(c)$ for all $h_n$ small enough. Now, split the sequence $h_n$ into $+$ve and $-$ve subsequences, and since each subsequence will also converge to zero. you get that the left and right hand limits  determining $f'(x)$ will have to be of different sign. Since both are equal to $f'(x)$, $f'(x) = 0$.

Comment: On a side note, I did not know this was called Fermat's theorem.

Comment: yes , it is Fermat's theorem

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Did  you understand my hint, or must I elaborate?

Comment: thanks for your hint , I try to do it by using your hint

Comment: That's great. Tell me when you are stuck again (if you are).

Comment: could you please provide me more ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55351/discussion-between-rian-asd-and----).

Comment: @ астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг  could you please help me I am stuck when I am trying to use your hint

Comment: I have answered your question below.